# Using Haskell addition function with both Num and Char values

Tags: haskell

I have a problem with the following function

```
sum f l1 l2 = (f l1) + (f l2)
```

It doesn't work with `sum length [1,2] ['a','b']`. When I try this I get

```
No instance for (Num Char) arising from the literal ‘1’
```

error so the problem is with types. When I try `:t` function, I get `sum :: Num a => (t -> a) -> t -> t -> a`. So, if I understand this correctly, I can't just use `+` function with both numerical and character values at the same time but I lack the deeper understanding of why exactly is this the case and how to fix it.

I tried a couple of things, like using `let` for one of the literals or `id` function, but this doesn't seem to work. Any help?

Comment: No that is correct, since `length :: [Int] -> Int` is not the same function as `length :: [Char] -> Int`. Here you thus force `f` to to have a specific type, but that is *not* applicable to both inputs `l1` and `l2`.

Comment: Oh, so I misunderstood it after all. Thank you. How can I fix it? I tried using `let` for one of the inputs so that they don't have the same type when using `length` function but that doesn't work.

Comment: Tuples handle multiple types. Lists are typed. Two types don't mix. `sequence [length.fst,length.snd] ([1,2], ['a','b'])`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When inferring types from your code, GHC will assume that you intend `f` to have a relatively simple type, and intend `l1` and `l2` to have the same type, so that both are suitable as input to `f`.

You apparently want to pass a polymorphic `f`, that can work on both `[Int]` and `[Char]`.  Depending how general you want to get, here are some options:

Works on lists, `f` must work on any list regardless of element type:

```
sum0 :: (forall x. [x] -> Int) -> [a] -> [b] -> Int
sum0 f l1 l2 = f l1 + f l2
```

Works on lists & other `Foldable` types (Vector, Set, Matrix), as long as both inputs are the same `Foldable`.  The first argument can be `length`, or something specific to the choice of `Foldable`, like `Set.size`.

```
sum1 :: (Num n, Foldable f) => (forall x. f x -> n) -> f a -> f b -> n
sum1 f l1 l2 = f l1 + f l2
```

Allow `l1` and `l2` to be *different* `Foldable` types.  `f` must work for *any* foldable.  `length` still qualifies, but `Set.size` isn't general enough.

```
sum2 :: (Num n, Foldable s, Foldable t) => (forall f x. Foldable f => f x -> n) -> s a -> t b -> n
sum2 f l1 l2 = f l1 + f l2
```

In practice, with a function this small, I think it's easier just to write `length l1 + length l2` at each use site than to define a function with any of the complex types above.  But it's nice to know we can write these types when we want to.

Comment: Which language extension do you use for this to work out..?

Comment: @Redu Should be `RankNTypes`, I'm pretty sure.

Comment: `RankNTypes` is what I used.  Thank you both for catching that missing piece of my answer.

Answer (score 3):

One approach (somewhat *ad hoc*) would be to alter the list values:

```
> sum length (map Right [1,2]) (map Left ['a', 'b'])
4
```

Instead of arguments of type `[Char]` and `Num a => [a]`, we have arguments of the common type `Num b => [Either b Char]`. This satisfies the inferred constraint (imposed by the fact that `f` is applied to both `l1` and `l2`) that the second and third arguments have the same type.

```
> :t sum
sum :: Num a => (t -> a) -> t -> t -> a
```

In fact, because we know that `length` doesn't care about the contents of its argument, we could discard any information about what is in the lists and map the same function over both:

```
> let foo = const () in sum length (map foo [1,2]) (map foo ['a', 'b'])
4
```

Since `const ()` ignores its argument and returns `()`, you simply replace each list with a equally long list of `()`:

```
> map (const ()) [1,2]
[(),()]
> map (const ()) ['a','b']
[(),()]
```